# filter outputs using select-string pipes

Tags: powershell, pipe, powershell-5.0

In bash, if I do the following, I will get all the environment variables with `wd` in them.

```
env | grep "wd"
```

Now, in Powershell, I know I could do

```
get-childitem env:wd*
```

But I want to pipe to select-string as a more generic approach, in order to filter what's coming in from its pipe, no matter what is to the left of the pipe.  Just like grep.

This doesn't filter anything, I get all environment variables.

```
get-childitem env: | out-string | select-string -Pattern wd
```

And this gets me nothing:

```
get-childitem env: | select-string -Pattern "wd"
```

I know I could use the following, and it is actually a better match if I filter only on the environment variable's name.  But what if I want a quick and dirty filter a la grep?  And especially, without knowing about the attributes of what's coming in from the pipe.

```
get-childitem env: | where-object {$_.Name -like "wd*"}
```

i.e. is there a Powershelll equivalent to **grep** usable in a pipe context, not just in the context of **file searches**, which `select-string` seems to cover well.

Comment: `Out-String -Stream`

Comment: `get-childitem env: | Out-String -Stream | select-string -Pattern wd` was just the ticket.  **Thx!** I dunno if you care, but I'll definitely accept it if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default `Out-String` produce single string object, which contain all the output, so the following filter will select or discard all output as whole. You need to use `-Stream` parameter of `Out-String` cmdlet to produce separate string object for each output line.

Answer (score 4):

Same answer, as a function and alias one can include in one's powershell profile:

```
function Find-Env-Variable (
           [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position=0)]
           [String]$Pattern){
    get-childitem ENV: | Out-String -Stream | select-string -Pattern "$Pattern"
}
Set-Alias findenv Find-Env-Variable
```